# WebEngineView - runJavaScript immediately (before page scripts are executed)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtwebengine

I have a QtQuick browser using WebEngineView.
I'd like to execute some JS code before normal scripts are loaded, to set a variable in `window` so that normal scripts can pick it up when they are executed.

I tried something like this:

```
WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        width: appContainer.width
        url: appContainer.pathUrl
        height: appContainer.height

        onLoadingChanged: {
            console.log('onLoadingChanged');
            webview.runJavaScript("window.someVariable = true");
        }
    }
```

I can see the "onLoadingChanged" log a couple of times, and the variable is set properly. However I have a very simple Vue app that I'm launching, with a simple static component and I try checking the variable in it's `mounted` callback:

```
mounted: function() {
    console.log(window.someVariable);
    setInterval(function() { console.log(window.someVariable); }, 1000);
}
```

The first console log prints `undefined` but every next interval tick prints `true`. So the variable is set properly, but it's done after the initial page load (or even after `DOMContentLoaded`)

Is there any way to set this variable automatically before everything else happens?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer: using userScripts property. I thought it's static and I needed to inject the script conditionally, but it can be done this way too.

```
 WebEngineScript {
        id: scriptID
        name: "scriptName"
        injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
        sourceCode: "window.someVariable = true"
        worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
    }


WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        width: appContainer.width
        url: appContainer.pathUrl
        height: appContainer.height

        userScripts: [ scriptID ]
        // or conditionally, I actually wanted to check if Loader component is loaded
        userScripts: loaderObj.status == Loader.Ready ? [ scriptID ] : []
    }
```